# load 5 videos in one list on flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-sliver

I use [chewie](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/chewie/) plugin

I have 5 videos on the internet and want to load all 5 videos  on the list and when scrolling the list to show another video, first I want to stop the last video,

In other words, when the list view position is changed, playing video stop

## Video Class

```dart
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class VideoPleayre extends StatefulWidget {
  final String _videoUrl;
  VideoPleayre(this._videoUrl);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _VideoPleayreState();
  }
}

class _VideoPleayreState extends State<VideoPleayre> {
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
  ChewieController _chewieController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(widget._videoUrl);
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Chewie(
      controller: _chewieController,
    );
  }
}
```

## Main CLass Code

```dart
 Map<String,String> MySourceList = {
      "Address1",
      "Address2",
      "Address3",
    }

NotificationListener(
          child: ListView.builder(
              controller: _controller,
              itemCount: MySourceList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                VideoPleayre(
                  MySourceList[index],
                )
              }
          ),
          onNotification: (t) {
            if (t is ScrollEndNotification) {
              setState(() {
              });
            }
          },
        );
```

Comment: putting it inside listview should work

Comment: Did you found the answer?  because I also want to play videos inside the `listview.builder()`

Comment: You can put chewie player inside ListView wrapped with VisibilityDetector

Comment: How do your `main` class look like? Could you provide at least a [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Did any of you find a solution to this? I want to use VisibilityDetector but what happens when two videos are visible in a screen? How did you solve it, OP?